# Org Mobile staging area with a WebDAV: Unable to set 'org-mobile-directory' with TRAMP

Tags: tramp, mobileorg

I have a working Owncloud server, and I would like to use Org Mobile to sync my Org files with my phone.

Following "Setting up the staging area" in the info doc for Org Mobile, I have customized the variable `org-mobile-directory` to the directory where I want my files to be stored on the server. I have now the following in my `~/.emacs`:

```
 '(org-mobile-directory
   "/davs:MyUserName@MyIPaddress:/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/MyRemotePath/")
```

This syntax for the remote directory is what I understood from the TRAMP info docs.

When I run `org-mobile-push`, then after an expected message showing me the good certificate for my cloud and asking me if I am sure to connect, I always get "`Variable 'org-mobile-directory' must point to an existing directory`".

Is the syntax I am using correct? Am I missing something?

Notes:

- The path `/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/` is what I read in the settings of my Owncloud to specify the WebDAV address to applications.
- I have verified that `MyRemotePath` exists on my server.
- I have set `org-mobile-files` and I have verified that `org-directory` is set to an existing directory (if it matters, although the latter should only concern the pulling from the staging area).
- I eventually would like to use Mobileorg. I have managed to sync from the Mobileorg application to my Owncloud, but apparently I would need a file `index.org` in my server directory in order to sync from the server to the phone. And this file seems to be generated by `org-mobile-push`, which is what led me to this problem.

Comment: The doc string for org-mobile-directory just says "The WebDAV directory where the interaction with the mobile takes place." So try pointing it to a directory only, i.e. no login name. Perhaps start with the bit after webdav - you might have to play about with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; what do you mean exactly by "no login name"? Mounting the remote directory to my system? (eventually I would like to do it without having to mount anything). And also, what do you mean by "start with the bit after webdav"?

Comment: Modify "/davs:MyUserName@MyIPaddress:/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/MyRemotePath/". You could try "MyRemotePath" or "webdav/MyRemotePath" etc. etc. You've nothing to lose. Personally, I use cadaver for webdav.

Comment: @m43cap I had already tried such variations, with no improvement. Any other suggestions? Could it be a certificate problem?

Comment: Maybe. Are you able ping it? Maybe try with a server you know already works.

Comment: Quoting myself, `I have a working Owncloud server` :).

Comment: I encounter a similar problem. After upgrading to tramp 2.4.3.3 all tramp methods appear to be gone. This is my setting for `org-mobile-directory`: ```lisp
(setq org-mobile-directory /nextcloud:user@my.domain:/org/")
```
This is the message when trying to invoke `org-mobile-push`: Method 'nextcloud' is not known. Any help is appreciated! Thanks, Daniel

Answer (score 1):

The recent Tramp versions support the `nextcloud` method, which is also good for OwnCloud servers. You might have better Tramp support if you use the latest Tramp (via GNU ELPA), create on your local machine a NextCloud GNOME Account, and try it.

If there are further problems on the Tramp side, I might be able to help; I have configured several OwnCloud and NextCloud servers via Tramp already.

Comment: Thanks for your post! I am actually planning to migrate to Nextcloud in the following days, so I will try the latest Tramp when this is done. If it works I will mark your answer as the solution; otherwise I will let you know :).